# Convert full colour height map to greyscale

Tags: raster-conversion

I try to convert full colour map with colour range like this:
[image: heightmaplegend]

to greyscale. I use mostly Corel Photo-Paint (similiar functions to Adobe Photoshop), but maybe QGIS or ArcMap could help?

Comment: In QGIS, you can open your map, in the properties, display it with grayscale and export it in the composer, it's a workaround. But sincerely, I advise you to use some tools like ImageMagick, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13496080

Comment: Unfortunately my map is shared in pdf. I can transform it to png or jpg of course. Unfortunately linked ImageMagic method do not transform map in the way I want: in the bar above from black (left) to white (right), but with many light and dark peaks.